# how to increase and decrease the progress bar horizontal using two buttons in onClick view method(android)

Tags: android, android-progressbar

```
    mIncButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Increment);
    mIncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //mProgress.incrementProgressBy(1);
            //mProgress.setProgress(100 * mProgress.getProgress());
            mProgress.setProgress(0);
            mProgress.setMax(100);
            mProgress.setProgress(mProgress.getMax()/100*5);
        }
    });
```

I TRIED WITH DIFFERENT METHODS BUT I AM NOT ABLE TO GET IT
I NEED TO DO IT WITH ONCLICK VIEW ONLY.

[this is how layout look like and whenever i press increase button, that progress bar have to increase 5% of it and as same with decrease button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCggV.png)

Comment: Perhaps try removing the comment in front of `mProgress.incrementProgressBy(1);`. That seems like the only thing you should need

Comment: i even tried that...but its not working

Comment: Get rid of everything else. Why would you increment the progress and then reset it to zero on the next line?

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain a counter outside. Set max in xml only.

```
int progress = 0;

mIncButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Increment);
mIncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(progress < 100)
          progress += 5; 
        mProgress.setProgress(progress);
    }
});
mDecButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Decrement);
mIncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(progress > 0)
          progress -= 5; 
        mProgress.setProgress(progress);
    }
});
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: @SainathSetti can you please explain, what exactly problem you are facing while using the code.

Comment: When the [DECREASE] or [INCREASE] button is pressed, the progress bar decrements/increments by 5%. If it is at minimum or maximum, of course it does not go lower/higher, and an appropriate Toast is displayed.

Comment: Updated my answer and put maxProgress to 100 in xml only, let me know if further help needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. I was creating a quiz, where the progress bar had to increase if the user gave the right answer and decrease if its a wrong answer. So I simply did this.

```
int PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT = 10;
ProgressBar mProgress;

mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progress_Bar);

//for right answer 
mProgress.incrementProgressBar(PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT);

//for the wrong answer
mProgress.incrementProgressBar(-PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT);
```

So for your case

```
   int progress = 5;

mIncButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Increment);
mIncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   
    mProgress.incrementProgressBy(progress);
    }
});
mDecButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Decrement);
mDecButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
   
    mProgress.incrementProgressBy(-progress);
    }
});
```